# prove an equivalence norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, equivalence-relations

Consider the space $U=\lbrace f\in C^1[0,1]:f(0)=f(1)=0\rbrace$ and $p(f)=sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f'(t)|$ is a norm in $U$. Prove that $p$ is equivalent to the norm $\|·\|_{C^1}$ in U. I don't know how to prove this equivalence norm through fundamental theorem of Calculus. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $f \in U$, and $x \in [0,1]$ we have (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) $$\lvert f(x) \rvert = \left \lvert \int^x_0 f'(t) dt \right \rvert \le \int^x_0 \lvert f'(t) \rvert dt \le x p(f) \le p(f).$$ Since this holds for all $x$, you can pass to the supremum to conclude that $$\|f\|_{C^{0}} \le p(f)$$ for all $f \in U$. By definition, $$\|f\|_{C^1} = \|f\|_{C^0} + p(f).$$ Thus we see $$p(f) \le \|f\|_{C^1} \le 2 p(f).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is $\|·\|_{C^0}$ in your equation?

Comment: Following your notation, if $\|\cdot\|_{C^1}$ is the typical norm on $C^1[0,1]$, then $\|\cdot\|_{C^0}$ is the typical norm on $C^0[0,1]$. That is $$\|f \|_{C^0} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert f(x) \rvert.$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where did you use the fundamental theorem of calculus. Since it is defined as $\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$, and I think we need to apply the given condition that $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Comment: @delta Well there are a few versions of the fundamental theorem of calculus. In the one you showed, you have $F' = f$, so you could rewrite it like $$\int^b_a F'(t)dt = F(b) - F(a)$$ and that's exactly how I'm using with $b = x$ and $a = 0$: $$\int^x_0 f'(t) dt = f(x) - \underbrace{f(0)}_{\,\,\, = 0} = f(x).$$ This is why I can say $$\lvert f(x) \rvert = \left \lvert \int^x_0 f'(t) dt \right \rvert$$ in the first equation.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. But, I have another question. In your first equation, you wrote $$\int^x_0 \lvert f'(t) \rvert dt \le x p(f).$$ How did you get this?

Comment: Because $\lvert f'(t)\rvert \le p(f)$ and since $p(f)$ is a constant, you can just do the integral: $\int^x_0 p(f)dx = xp(f)$.